# Can I get the default template to not require items to build?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

The `Items to build` being added as a requirement in the default template appears to be doing so in the editor for `Activities.BuildSettings`? since I don't see it anywhere in the xaml. Or perhaps I could do something in the metadata collection to override the setting?

I want to run a custom task whether or not there is something being built with msbuild. What are my options?

Comment: Curiosity - if there is nothing being built, then why is the build running?

Comment: @John - An automated metrics task against an existing .net binaries folder using the new vs2010 metrics.exe commandline tool, we want to measure code quality and sql quality in an automated method in tfs2010 that we hope will be adopted by the teams and their builds plugged into this template after showing what it can do.

Comment: why not simply run the metrics after each build, as part of the build?

Comment: @john - the build itself is happening on ccnet, not tfs, the source is checked into tfs2008, not tfs2010. So I want to use tfs2010 wf builds to run this task and show what it can do, allowing for teams to move their build process over to tfs2010 as they can.

Comment: Hi.  Somehow this was marked as [tag:untagged] so as part of an [ongoing cleanup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399176) I added the tags that seemed appropriate.  Please edit and fix if these are not the appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a dummy project for TFS to build.

Comment: As additional information for anyone that winds up here, I pointed the update template at a source directory with nothing build-able in it and the process also worked that way

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a targets file in the items to build. This targets file is using the msbuild syntax. In there you can specify what you want.

Comment: My question is, how can I disable the requirement to have something listed there? while keeping all the default functionality that would engage if there is.

Comment: you mean you just specify the path to a .targets file? May I specify more than one?